# Prove that a set has measure null

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

If i have $f$ a Lipschitz continuos function and i know that $meas(f(A))=0$. I know that a Lipschitz continuos function maps null sets to null sets, but how can I prove that $meas(A)=0 $ ?
$f:\mathbb{R}^N\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^N$. $A=\{x : f \hspace{0.1cm}\text{is differentiable in $x$ and $Df=0$}\{$. Since $f$ is Lipschitz continuos i have used the area formula 
$\int_{B} |det Df(x)|dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}n(B\cap f^{-1}(y))dy$

where $n$ is counting measure. Since

$n(B\cap f^{-1}(y))$
\begin{cases}
=0 &\text{se $y\notin f(B)$} \\
\geq 1 &\text{se $y\in f(B)$}
\end{cases}

i have proved that $meas(f(A))=\int_{f(A)} dy\leq\int_{A}|det Df(x)|dx=0$. But i have to prove that $meas(A)=0$. Thank you.

Comment: Where is your function defined? Where is your measure defined? Is this a general measure or the lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible without other hypothesis. In fact take $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=1$ for every $x\in [0,1]$, then $f$ is trivially a Lipschitz continuos function. Now, take $A=[0,1]$ then the Lebesgue measure of $f(A)=\{1\}$ is equal to zero on the other hands the lebesgue measure of $A$ is $1$.

Comment: What other hypothesis can i add?

Comment: Have you some other hypothesis?

Comment: Yes, i want prove the Alexandrov's Theorem that is presented here https://carma.newcastle.edu.au/jon/Preprints/Books/CUP/CUPold/np-convex.pdf at page 164. My question is a piece of demonstration. Thanks !